# Use Binding value as key for Translation with MarkupExtension

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I'm using my own custom localization library that is based on [this tutorial](http://wpftutorial.net/LocalizeMarkupExtension.html) with extended features.

Works pretty nifty, but now I want to use it within a `ItemControl` with a `Template` for all available languages and get localized values depending on a property of the items.

ViewModel:

```
public IEnumerable<CultureInfo> AvailableLanguages
{
    get
    {
        return TranslationManager.Instance.AvailableLanguages;
    }
}
```

View:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding AvailableLanguages}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type glo:CultureInfo}">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Image Width="32" Height="24"
                       Source="{loc:Translate {Binding TwoLetterISOLanguageName}}"/>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding DisplayName}"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

Obviously using a `Binding` as Parameter won't work, because of some limitations of `MarkupExtensions` (you can see the basic implementation in the link above).

Is there a way to work around this issue? Will my only alternative be to do this whole stuff in the code behind?

Comment: What is `TwoLetterISOLanguageName`?

Comment: It's a property of [CultureInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.globalization.cultureinfo), for example "en" for English, "de" for German, and so on